# What is the importance of the game scoresheet?

Tags: officiating, scoring

In sports games, what is the main importance of the scoresheet?
As in the image below?

[image: scoresheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the scoresheet is the official record of the result of the game. In most sports I've played, it is signed by the captain (or other representative) of each team at the end of the match to show that they agree with the final score, and then sent to the organising body to show the result of the match (and other secondary things like any disciplinary sanctions applied to players).

To quote from the [offical volleyball rules](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf) (just as that's the sport I'm probably most familiar with):

> AT THE END OF THE MATCH, the team captain: thanks the referees and signs the score sheet to ratify the result

I'd imagine similar things exist for other sports.

Comment: Field hockey: Umpiring 3.3.d, *"a written record of goals scored and cards issued must be kept by both umpires and confirmed at the end of the match."* Football: Law 5.3, para 1 *"The referee: ... acts as timekeeper, keeps a record of the match and provides the appropriate authorities with a match report, including information on disciplinary action and any other incidents that occurred before, during or after the match"*